# The current path, Envs/python-projects/learnpy/static/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

*Using the URLconf defined in learnpy.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
[name='index']
admin/
The current path, Envs/python-projects/learnpy/static/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css, didn't match any of these.*

Above error occuring in create django static page Please help me

**See belowe image:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tlg8Q.png)

**Myapp url:  travello/urls.py**

from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [ path('',views.index, name='index')]

**Main app urls: learnpy/urls.py**

from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('travello.urls')),

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

]

**Myapp view file: travello/views.py**

from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):

return render(request, 'index.html')

**In index.html**

{% load static %}

set above code in my index.html file

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not added the static URLs path to your project.

1. Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your
   INSTALLED_APPS.
2. In your settings file, define STATIC_URL, for example:

   `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
3. In your templates, use the static template tag to build the URL for
   the given relative path using the configured STATICFILES_STORAGE.

   ```
   {% load static %}
   <img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
   ```
4. Also you need to add static directory in your settings file

```
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    ]
```

for further reading please check the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Comment: I also set this two think

Comment: yes   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'assets')

Comment: {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Travello</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="Travello template project">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link  href="{% static '/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css">

This code for index.html

Comment: I follow this tutorial #10 and #11 the same as creating code but still not working

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8Uem148uOU&list=PLsyeobzWxl7poL9JTVyndKe62ieoN-MZ3&index=95

Comment: can you try to hit this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css and see if it works

Comment: Update your <link> line in your html file to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css"/>`

Comment: I hit this url 127.0.0.1:8000/static/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Envs/python-projects/learnpy/static/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css
Using the URLconf defined in learnpy.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='index']
admin/
The current path, Envs/python-projects/learnpy/static/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: Not working this 127.0.0.1:8000/static/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css"/> also not working

Comment: have you added static url in your main urls.py like: `urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT`

Comment: # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...  I can't understand this also document_root this one?

Comment: Watch this video which  i follow:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tt3mgy2ECug&list=PLsyeobzWxl7poL9JTVyndKe62ieoN-MZ3&index=96

Comment: Please refer to this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development you need to add static url in the urls.py file. Just append  `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT` this line to your urlpatterns list at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Required Static file Dir in Django Setting file. 
then u resolve this error.

please follow this link for more understanding.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

```
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Comment: I also set this in settings.py file

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 'django-bootstrap4'? If so, you should add 'bootstrap4' to 'INSTALLED_APPS' in your project's 'settings.py' file.